# Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor after .NET 8 upgrade

Tags: .net-8.0, ef-core-8.0

I updated my project from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and now I get this error on every query:

Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'

I try the same thing on another PC but I get the same error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you delete all obj and bin directories? And close and reopen the solution. Also check if all packages are updated, not only the core.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a conflict between two packages in two projects of the solution:
"EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId" Version="4.0.0"
and
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId" Version="8.0.0"

I removed the first one

Comment: mark it as answer